# How to place Cards by Mosaic way?

Tags: html, css, layout, grid, floating

The height every of the card needs to be `max-content`.

I've set `height` to specific values for demonstrating the problem.

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-column-gap: 5%;
    grid-auto-rows: min-content;
}

.card {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="card" style="height: 100px">
  1
 </div>
  <div class="card" style="height: 200px; background-color: yellow">
  2
 </div>
  <div class="card" style="height: 200px; background-color: yellow">
  3
 </div>
  <div class="card" style="height: 200px">
  4
 </div>
  <div class="card" style="height: 200px; background-color: green">
  5
 </div>
  <div class="card" style="height: 200px; background-color: red">
  6
 </div>
  <div class="card" style="height: 200px">
    7
 </div>
</div>
```

The problem is - There is a **White space** between **1** and **3** cards.
Need to achive - no this extra white space.
Card **3** needs to be excactly after **1**

I've tried - `grid-auto-rows: min-content` - but it makes no result.

Cards with different height need to be exactly one after another one. without extra white space. (By Mosaic way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What you're trying to achieve is called **Masonry Layout**.

You'll find a lot of example here https://css-tricks.com/piecing-together-approaches-for-a-css-masonry-layout/
I hope it will help you to find which option better fits your needs.